# a pattern sentence asking questions

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

Here is a pattern sentence asking a question: "Where did you get that book?" 
Another sentence goes: "What made you decide to leave Russia?"

Why not to use "What did make you decide to leave Russia?" as in the first example?

I don't understand the following: both sentences have past tense but only one uses "did" to make the interrogative sentence. Why is *did* omitted? Perhaps it's just the way it is...

Comment: Related: [How do I use auxiliary do in questions?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31431/2127). One of your question sentences is a "subject question", the other is an "object question".

Answer (score 4):

In open interrogatives, the inversion only occurs when the wh-word is not the subject. This is why the inversion occurs in the first sentence because *where* corresponds to *adjunct* in the answer to the question.

Where did you get that book? --> I get it **from the library**.

Inversion does not occur in the second sentence because the wh-word is the subject.

What made you decide to leave Russia-->**The war** made me decide to leave Russia.

Comment: +1 There's a somewhat more technical discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/139424/32)

Answer (score 3):

Note, you can use "did" there, but in that case it acts as an intensifier.

> You say you didn't leave because of the political situation. So, what *did* make you decide to leave Russia?